# Login log for all users

Tags: 18.04, login

Is there a log available where we can see login attempts, both failed and successful, for all users in 18.04 ? Also, any possible info about last logged in for a user ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a *single* log, but successful logins are logged in `/var/log/wtmp` and unsuccessful ones in `/var/log/btmp`. These are binary files, but are readable via the `last` and `lastb` commands. From `man last`:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>        last  searches  back through the /var/log/wtmp file (or the file desig‐
>        nated by the -f option) and displays a list of all users logged in (and
>        out)  since  that  file was created.
> ```

and

> ```
>        lastb is the same as last, except that by default it shows a log of the
>        /var/log/btmp file, which contains all the bad login attempts.
> ```

---

Note that access to the `btmp` (failed login) file is restricted for security reasons: while neither file records password strings by design, a not uncommon cause of failed logins is when users mistakenly type their password into the login field. Hence `sudo` is needed when running `lastb`.

Also note that the files are rotated - you may wish to look back through earlier logs ex.

```
sudo lastb -f /var/log/btmp.1
```

Comment: I tried `lastb`, it says permission denied. Tried `sudo` , but that too didn't throw a list. When tried with `sudo`, it simply gives the creation date of `btmp` file.

Comment: `sudo last` works and no log with lastb? Maybe there is no login failure...

Comment: I asked this question because I mistyped the password a few times. I was curious about how I will track such failed attempts. `last` works without `sudo`. It is `lastb` which do not give a list, `sudo` or not.

Comment: @user227495 please see update - if plain `sudo lastb` doesn't show the expected attempt, try looking back through previous logs (`/var/log/btmp.1` and so on)

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver . But there is only one `btmp`. Nothing in `log` folder with `btmp` varients.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package called "audit". You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install auditd
```

Then you will need to start and enable it to start at boot:

```
sudo systemctl start audit
sudo systemctl enable audit
```

All login attempt whether successful or not will log to /var/log/auth.log (ssh logins are already logged there as well). Also the package has a reporting ability:

Successful attempts summary:

```
aureport -l --success --summary -i | less
```

Failed attempts report:

```
aureport -au -i --failed | less
```

You can swap "--failed" with "--success" or vice-versa in the above commands.